# Laravel how to make Test for Scope

Tags: php, laravel

i want to test my scope in my Statistic Model --->

```
  class Statistic extends Model
    {
    use HasTranslations;

  use HasFactory;

            public $translatable = ['country'];

     protected $guarded = ['id'];

      public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters): Builder
          {
    return $query->when($filters['search'] ?? false, fn ($query, $search) => $query- 
    >where(DB::raw('lower(country)'), 'like', '%' . strtolower($search) . '%'));
        }
      }
```

how can i organize this?

How to correctly write Feature test for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
class StatisticScopesTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function is_has_a_scope_filter()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(0, Statistic::count());
        $this->assertEquals(0, Statistic::filter(['search' => 'PT'])->count());

        Statistic::factory()->create(['country' => 'PT']);

        $this->assertEquals(1, Statistic::count());
        $this->assertEquals(1, Statistic::filter(['search' => 'PT'])->count());
        $this->assertEquals(0, Statistic::filter(['search' => 'EN'])->count());
    }
}
```

- 2 assertions for the empty case
- create on entry for a country
- 3 assertions for the case with one entry